# Kotlin - R.string.navigation_drawer_open, Não está sendo importado?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, navigation-drawer

Estou tentando aprender Kotlin, mas, não Estou conseguindo utilizar o `navigation_drawer_open`, e nem o `navigation_drawer_close`, como demonstra a imagem anexada

Alguém saberia me dar uma sugestão do que fazer para corrigir o problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Elas estão declaradas no strings.xml?
Normalmente essas strings são criadas automaticamente, aparentemente elas não foram, então é só adicioná-las ao strings.xml:

```
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
```